# Groups with a unique composition series

Tags: gr.group-theory

Which finite groups $G$ have a unique composition series? I don't mean in the sense of the Jordan-Holder theorem, but rather actually unique.

Some examples are the cyclic groups $C_{p^n}$ and the symmetric group $S_3$ (which has the unique normal subgroup $A_3$).

Comment: The symmetric group $S_n$ is an example for every $n\neq 4$, isn't it? Other examples: simple groups, $\operatorname{SL}(2,q)$ for $q\geq 4$.

Comment: In other words, you ask which finite groups $G$ have $N(G)$ totally ordered, where $N(G)$ is the set of normal subgroups. Some discussion is here: http://people.bath.ac.uk/masgcs/problem/commentary10.html

Comment: @YCor: The property here is stronger: for example, $S_4$ has $N(G)$ totally ordered, namely $1< V_4 < A_4 < S_4$, but $V_4$ has three different composition series. In fact, the set of subnormal subgroups must be totally ordered (in which case it happens that every subnormal subgroup is normal).

Comment: Ah OK sure, you're right.

Comment: When $G$ has only two composition factors, the composition series is unique if and only if $G$ is not the product of two simple groups.  So any nonsplit extension of a simple group by another simple group is an example.

Comment: @spin: Note that the (now proved) Schreir conjecture tells us that you can't have an extension of a finite non-Abelian simple group acted on non-trivially by another finite non-Abelian simple group.

Comment: @YCor: That would be the question of which finite groups have a unique chief series, which is a more difficult question, e.g. if the group G is an example, and G has an irreducible faithful representation V over a finite field, then all the extensions V.G are examples.

Answer (score 15):

Such a group $G$ must have a unique minimal normal subgroup $M,$ which must itself be simple by the uniqueness of the composition series. If $G$ is a $p$-group, it follows by induction that $G$ is cyclic ($G/M$ is cyclic by induction, so $G$ is Abelian, and hence cyclic by the uniqueness of $M$). Suppose then that $G$ is not a $p$-group.

If $G$ is solvable, then it follows from the above ( and the uniqueness of the composition series) that $F(G)$ is a cyclic $p$-group. Then $G/F(G)$ is Abelian, hence cyclic of order $q^{m}$ for some prime $q \neq p$ (and in fact $q^{m}$ divides $p-1).$

Suppose then that $G$ is not solvable. Note that $G/G^{\prime}$ is a cyclic $p$-group for some prime $p,$ by the uniqueness of the composition series. More generally, $G/G^{(\infty )}$ has one of the structures above, where $G^{(\infty)}$ is the terminal member of the derived series of $G.$

We next describe the structure of $G^{(\infty)},$ so, for ease of exposition, we assume from now on that $G$ is perfect. Then since $F(G)$ is cyclic, we have $F(G) = Z(G)$, which is a (possibly trivial) cyclic $p$-group for some prime $p.$ Furthermore, $F(G)$ is the largest solvable normal subgroup of $G$.

Then, as above, $G/Z(G)$ has a unique minimal normal subgroup, which is non-Abelian simple, and has trivial centralizer. Using the Schreier conjecture, it follows that $G$ is quasi-simple in the case under consideration.

In summary, a general finite group $G$ with a unique composition series has one of the following structures:

$G$ may be a cyclic $p$-group for some prime $p.$

$F(G)$ may be a cyclic $p$-group, and $G$ is the semidirect product of $F(G)$ with a cyclic $q$-group for some prime $q \neq p.$

$G$ is not solvable, $F^{\ast}(G)$ is quasi-simple, and $Z(G)$ is a cyclic $p$-group for some prime $p.$ Furthermore, $G/F^{\ast}(G)$ is solvable with a unique composition series, so with one of the structures above (note also that $G/F^{\ast}(G)$ is a subgroup of the outer automorphism group of the simple group $F^{\ast}(G)/Z(G)$).
(Note that any group with any of these structures does indeed have a unique composition series).

Comment: What does $F(G)$ stand for?

Comment: $F(G)$ is the largest nilpotent normal subgroup of the finite group $G$, the Fitting subgroup of $G$. Also, $F^{\ast}(G)$ is the generalized Fitting subgroup of $G$.